# IntelliJ IDEA - Directories appearing in Project Files but not in Project

Tags: intellij-idea

So I created an empty project, but when I create a new directory in the Project window, it does not show up.  The directory is actually created, and if I navigate to the Project Files list I can see it there, but as far as I can tell there is no way to make even my src folder part of the actual project.  This creates all kinds of problems when I have to move/refactor files, and I'm amazed that something so common and simple is so difficult.

Comment: Do you have *Show excluded files* enabled in the *Project* view settings? See if enabling it make the folder appear... Project the issue can be reproduced with plus some screenshots would be helpful

Comment: Yes, I've pretty much always had that enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a folder, not a package. If ur using maven or grade, can I suggest u use them to generate an intelij project for you. The command escapes me but a quick Google should tell you

Comment: It's a Node project, I initialized it with npm init.  I've also been Googling for the last half hour and maybe I've missed something but I can't find a solution.  In Visual Studio, for example, you can accomplish this with a simple action from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually mark your directory as a sources root:

[image]

Comment: Sorry i'm not at home at the moment so i can't get you the exact steps, but maybe go on github and download a simple node project, and go into file and import project and it should all be there

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I'm also at work and Imgur is blocked here.  We're trying to create a custom React template and add in the required configuration as needed.  I did see an answer about adding Additional Source Roots, but the options described appear to be missing or for an older version.  And I'm sure I could start from a different project and remove all the parts I don't need, but that's a suboptimal workaround when adding a folder to an empty project should be an extremely straightforward operation.

Comment: Back home and able to see your image.  This option does not appear in my context menu.  I should note that this only occurs on macOS, it does show up on my PC at home.  Any ideas where the action could be hidden in the Mac version?  **EDIT:** Noticed you're also using Mac.  Super strange.  I'm using IDEA Ultimate v2019.2 and it's simply not there.